# Как разбить цикл wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Добрый вечер!

Подскажите как разбить цикл на группы по 4 поста?

Нужно чтоб каждые 4 поста получили обертку div.swiper-slide

```
 $bcat = get_category_by_slug('blog');
    $bid = $bcat->ID;
    $n = 12;
    $c = 1;

$recent = new WP_Query("cat=".$id."&posts_per_page=".$n);
 while ($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
        get_template_part('blog-block');
        wp_reset_postdata();
        $c++;
    endwhile;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $bcat = get_category_by_slug('blog');
 $bid = $bcat->ID;
 $n = 12;
 $c = 1;

 $recent = new WP_Query("cat=".$id."&posts_per_page=".$n);
while ($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();

    if($c%4 === 0){
       echo '<div class="swiper-slide>';
    }
    get_template_part('blog-block');
    if($c%4 === 0){
       echo '</div>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
   $c++
endwhile;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @АнтонГолубков если ответ решил Вашу проблему, проголосуйте за него и поставьте галочку. Спасибы в комментариях, конечно, приятны, но выделить правильный ответ проще по рейтингу.